# Javascript callback function result function triggered too early

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a callback function to delay the function that adds a product to cart as seen below.

The `productAddToCartForm.submit(this)` is still being called too early. I've also tried the promise function (though I'm not sure if it is applicable here).

The callback function appends a hidden input with a variable I need posted. The add to cart function is being called before it is appended.

The only thing that works right now is a timeout function but I don't want to do that.

`Console.log` titled 1-4 ARE logging. Any ideas?

```
updatePrices(IDs, function () {
    //setInterval(function(){productAddToCartForm.submit(this)},2000);
    console.log("3. finished function and returned");
    $j("input").promise().done(function () {
        console.log("4.Finished! ");
        productAddToCartForm.submit(this);
    });
});

function updatePrices(IDs, callback) {
    console.log("1. entering update Prices function");
    //... A BUNCH OF N/A CODE, ASSUME BASEPRICE 2.50
    if (IDs.length == 1) {
        console.log("2. IDs equals one");
        $j('.priceBlock input').remove();
        $j('.details' + IDs[i] + ' .priceBlock').append('<input type="hidden" name="customPrice" value="' + basePrice + '"/>');
        //return;
    }
    if (callback) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because `$j( "input" ).promise()` fires immediately; what did you think it was supposed to do?

Comment: Well the docs page had it where an animation finishes. I thought mayne when all inputs were appended it might fire. Was just an experiment. How do I check that something has finished appending?

Comment: So you're saying that `updatePrices()` adds the input field, but inside the callback the element is not there yet when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that even though the element has been added to the DOM, the form isn't refreshed yet by the time your callback function is called.

You have mentioned you don't wish to use it, but without a reproducible fiddle I can only suggest `setTimeout()`:

```
if (callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 1);
}
```

This briefly hands over control to the browser so that it can do some internal bookkeeping and it's (unfortunately) a proven way for these kinds of issues.

Comment: Is that used in place of  if (callback) {callback();} like I have it in updatePrices function? If so, I'm still having issues.

Comment: Yes. If you're still having issues, take out the submit at the end and manually submit the form. Does that work?